# You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: c#, mysql

What am I doing wrong? Is there some C# translate trouble or something?

```
string commandText = 
  @"SELECT sc.sc_n,
           sc.provider_n,
           sc.sc_external_id,
           sc.sc_external_name 
      FROM t_supplier_codification sc 
     WHERE sc.product_articul IS NULL 
       AND (sc.sc_external_name != "") 
       AND sc_count >= 1 
       AND provider_n=19 
       AND LENGTH(sc.sc_external_name)>=10 
       AND sc_external_name NOT LIKE '%лента%' 
       AND sc_external_name NOT LIKE '%камера%' 
       AND sc_external_name NOT LIKE '%Replica%' 
       AND sc_external_name NOT LIKE '%ET%' 
       AND sc_external_name LIKE ''
  ORDER BY sc_external_name";
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '") AND sc_count >= 1 AND provider_n=19 AND LENGTH

Comment: `(sc.sc_external_name!='') `

Comment: you might want to escape those double quotes in _name!="" or use single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
(sc.sc_external_name!='')
```

as the double quotes terminate your string. Also, single quotes are normally used for string literals in SQL, double quotes are used for column names (and other objects).

Comment: It's a verbatim string, so the two double quotes are read as a single double quote, not as terminating the string, but single quotes would be another option.

Comment: SQL uses single quotes for values, double quotes are used for objects.

Comment: @juharr Good point about the verbatim string, I missed that and that it could be escaped. Single quotes would be a better choice anyway as it's more in line with the standard.

Answer (score 0):

When using verbatim strings with the @ at the beginning you have to delimit double quotes with a double qoute.  So the following

```
@"(sc.sc_external_name!="")"
```

is actually the string

```
(sc.sc_external_name!=")
```

To fix it you just need to add two more double quotes like

```
@"(sc.sc_external_name!="""")"
```

Or more simply just use single quotes instead

```
@"(sc.sc_external_name!='')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your double quotes change them to single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Double quote should be removed, Try this one:

```
        string commandText = @"SELECT sc.sc_n,sc.provider_n,sc.sc_external_id,sc.sc_external_name
                FROM t_supplier_codification sc 
                WHERE sc.product_articul IS NULL 
                AND (sc.sc_external_name!='') AND sc_count >= 1 AND provider_n=19 AND LENGTH(sc.sc_external_name)>=10 AND sc_external_name NOT LIKE '%лента%' 
                AND sc_external_name NOT LIKE '%камера%' AND sc_external_name NOT LIKE '%Replica%' AND sc_external_name NOT LIKE '%ET%' AND sc_external_name LIKE ''
                ORDER BY sc_external_name";
```